# Presentation complexes with same homology and different fundamental groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, finite-groups

If we start with a perfect group $G$ of deficiency zero then there is a presentation $P$ of $G$ such that the number of relations and the number of generators for $P$ are the same. For such $P$, the presentation complex $X_P$ is homologous to a point, i.e., $H_i(X_P;\mathbb{Z})=H_i({\mathrm{pt}};\mathbb{Z})$ for all $i$. One can prove this using Mayer Vietoris. In this context, I have a general question as follows:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two presentation complexes of two finite groups $G_1$ and $G_2$. Assume that $H_i(X;\mathbb{Z})=H_i(Y;\mathbb{Z})$ for $i=1,2$. Is there a relation between $G_1$ and $G_2$? Can we say $G_1$ and $G_2$ are the same up to some perturbation of perfect groups with some deficiency condition?

I do apologize if the questions are silly. I will be really grateful for any sort of help.

Comment: The answer is certainly "no" -- $G_1$ and $G_2$ will typically have nothing to do with each other (beyond the necessary fact that their abelianisations must be isomorphic). But the question is phrased vaguely, so it's not clear what kind of answer might convince you.

Comment: "Can we say $G_1$ and $G_2$ are the same up to some *perturbation* of perfect groups..." What is a perturbation in this context?